# How can I split the dataset obtained from image_dataset_from_directory into data and labels?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to build a CNN in TensorFlow with Python. I've loaded my images into a dataset as follows:

```
dataset = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
    "train_data", shuffle=True, image_size=(578, 260),
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

However, if I want to use train_test_split or fit_resample on this dataset, I need to separate it into data and labels. I'm new to TensorFlow and don't know how to do this. Would really appreciate any help.

Comment: Are your labels a part of ‘train_data’?

Comment: @AloneTogether yes.

Comment: How is your data structured in your folder?

Comment: @AloneTogether I have 5 sub-folders full of images, organized in the same way I want the data classified

Comment: Thanks for the solution, am still trying to make it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `subset` parameter to separate your data into `training` and `validation`.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import pathlib

dataset_url = "https://storage.googleapis.com/download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz"
data_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('flower_photos', origin=dataset_url, untar=True)
data_dir = pathlib.Path(data_dir)


train_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="training",
  image_size=(256, 256),
  seed=1,
  batch_size=32)

val_ds = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  validation_split=0.2,
  subset="validation",
  seed=1,
  image_size=(256, 256),
  batch_size=32)

for x, y in train_ds.take(1):
  print('Image --> ', x.shape, 'Label --> ',  y.shape)
```

```
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 2936 files for training.
Found 3670 files belonging to 5 classes.
Using 734 files for validation.
Image -->  (32, 256, 256, 3) Label -->  (32,)
```

As for your labels, according to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory):

> Either "inferred" (labels are generated from the directory structure),
> None (no labels), or a list/tuple of integer labels of the same size
> as the number of image files found in the directory. Labels should be
> sorted according to the alphanumeric order of the image file paths
> (obtained via os.walk(directory) in Python).

So just try iterating over the `train_ds` and see if they are there. You can also use the parameters `label_mode` to refer to the kind of labels you have and `class_names` to explicitly list your classes.

If your classes are inbalanced, you can use the `class_weights` parameter of `model.fit(*)`. For more information, check out this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/13490/how-to-set-class-weights-for-imbalanced-classes-in-keras).